# How to write the characters in Unicode block "Miscellaneous Technical"

Tags: symbols, overleaf, unicode, newunicodechar

I want to include some special Unicode string to my overleaf report. In particular the Straightness ⏤ (U+23E4), Cylindricity ⌭ (U+232D), Symmetry ⌯ (U+232F), and Electrical Arrow ⌁  (U+2301). However, it seems that these symbols are not supported by the default setting of overleaf.

I have tried many solutions suggested in the forum, but they are not applicable (or to my very limited knowledge about latex) for my case. I have tried to compile my document with Pdflatex, LuaLatex and XeLatex compilers, but I haven't achieved the goal.

Could you help me to include them into a document (scrbook) on overleaf? An alternative solution (with TikZit drawing) would also be fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with lualatex or xelatex you can directly use the symbols as long as your font has these symbols.

One example which works on overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/read/wqppmhhqdndf#bc6bf0):

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\foo}{STIX Two Math Regular}

\begin{document}

Straightness {\foo ⏤} (U+23E4)

Cylindricity {\foo ⌭} (U+232D)

Symmetry {\foo ⌯} (U+232F)

Electrical Arrow {\foo ⌁} (U+2301)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @John You're welcome!